# is it possible to create builds in asp.net mvc3 using jira and ant

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ant, build, jira

I am working on the daily builds using ant and jira for one of asp.net mvc3 project, I searched so many forums for this but I am not able to find any solution for this,

Is it possible to create daily builds using ant and jira (or any other tool) on the server which will result as following

```
www.example.com/build1
www.example.com/build2
www.example.com/build3
...
```

every build should be working

waiting for reply

Thanks

Comment: Did you mean `nant`? `ant` is for Java.

Comment: how do you create a build using jira? jira is a bug tracking / project management software....

Comment: yes it is possible to create builds using jira's plugins,
https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRASTUDIO/Working+with+Builds

Answer (score 0):

what you want is continuous integration. You probably want to go with Hudson or Jenkins. Then you can have ant or microsoft build tools to do the daily or hourly or whatever builds for you.

You can track the builds, also you can deploy the builds with specific IDs etc.

with JIRA you can track the bugs etc.

Comment: I would put out a shout for TeamCity in that list as well.

Comment: Darth Vader thanks for the reply, if I use microsoft's msdeploy tool will it work with mvc3, right now I am using ant to create the builds and I can only host one build at time on IIS6, If I create any new build I have to update the configuration in IIS.